# Plugin Licences

Tags: add-on

I'd like to write a plug-in to accomplish something for my job, and I'm trying to figure out if the licensing options are such that I can convince management to let me do it.

My company would want to be able to distribute the plug-in to collaborators, while preventing its further distribution. There are two things I'm considering:

1. Potential clients getting a free copy (I'm not *too* concerned about this)
2. Our competitors getting a copy and using *our own* software elbow us out of potential clients - this, I'd like to prevent

The ["Can I sell plug-ins for Blender" section of the FAQ](http://www.blender.org/support/faq/) notes that selling plugins is OK, provided they're GPL'd. This seems to me like a "one time sale" situation. In other words, why would a second client ever buy the plug-in, if they could just get it for free from the first?

Is there any way to license a plugin such that we can feel comfortable letting our collaborators use it, while at same time as preventing the opportunity for competitors to use it against us?

Comment: Blender's use of GPLv3+ is not unique or special, there is a lot of information online on GPL use, I think we can't realistically give good legal advice here. See: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/422/are-licensing-questions-off-topic/423#423